# Pyspark: Check whether boolean column contains only True values

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Working in databricks, I've got a dataframe which looks like this:

```
columns = ["a", "b", "c"]
data = [(True, True, True), (True, True, True), (True, False, True)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df.display()
```

[image]

I'd like to select only those columns of the dataframe in which not all values are True.
In pandas I would use `df['a'].all()` to check whether all values of column "a" are True. Unfortunately, I don't find an equivalent in pyspark.
I found a solution for the problem but it seems much too complicated:

```
df.select(*[column for column in df.columns 
            if df.select(column).distinct().collect() != 
            spark.createDataFrame([True], 'boolean').toDF(column).collect()])
```

The solution returns what I want:

[image]

Is there an easier way of doing this in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pyspark, you can try like this also, without creating new dataframe in every iteration.

```
df.select(*[column for column in df.columns 
            if ('False' in [str(i).split('=')[-1][:-1] for i in df.select(column).distinct().collect()])
            ]).show()
```

**This is my sample data:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**(Or)**

```
df.select(*[column for column in df.columns 
            if (df.select(column).distinct().count()>=2 or df.select(column).distinct().collect()[0][0]!=True)
            ]).show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I prefer the second option you mentioned since it is more explicit in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach which follows a similar operational model to that of pandas

```
def is_all(c):
    return (F.sum(F.col(c).astype('int')) == F.count(c)).alias(c)

# create a boolean mask, 
# for e.g in pandas this would similar to df.all(axis=0)
mask = df.agg(*[is_all(c) for c in columns]).collect()[0]

# Use the boolean mask to filter the columns
result = df.select(*[c for c in columns if not mask[c]])
```

Result

```
+-----+
|    b|
+-----+
| true|
| true|
|false|
+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a good solution too!